# Using Spring AOP to Log methods of a Spring framework class

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Is there a way to use Spring AOP to log the entry and exit of a method under spring framework's class?
**For Eg:**
I wish to log extry and exit of 
`refresh()` in `org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext` class
I tried the following. But no luck :(

```
@Around("execution(* org.springframework.context.*(..))")
public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Entry Into Method : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("Arguments : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));

    joinPoint.proceed();

    System.out.println("Exit from Method : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
}
```

But I end up with bean creation exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work, simply because you are trying to intercept some methods on a class that after creation (and after calling `refresh()`) it starts creating the beans necessary for AOP.

I believe you need to use AspectJ. Define as aspect like the following `MyAspect.aj`:

```
package com.foo.bar;

public aspect MyAspect {

    static final void println(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    pointcut aroundAppContext():
        execution(* org.springframework.context.support.*.*(..));

    Object around(): aroundAppContext() {
        println("Intercepted message: " + thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName());
        println("in class: " + thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getName());
        Object result = proceed();
        println("  result: " + result);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Define in your project a `META-INF/aop.xml` file with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>

    <weaver> <!-- options="-debug -verbose -showWeaveInfo"> -->
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include  within="org.springframework.context.support.*"/>
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="com.foo.bar.MyAspect"/>
    </aspects>

</aspectj>
```

and run your project with `-javaagent` option, just like the reference documentation is mentioning [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw).